# Load function with login_redirect

Tags: redirect, login

I'm trying to load a message after successful login on the front end.

I have the script that works as a function,

```
function myscript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('<div class="item login">Success! You\'re now signed in.</div>').appendTo('.pop-notice').delay(6000).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });
  });
</script>
<?php }
```

Which I then try to load into the footer on login_redirect.

```
function my_login_redirect() {
 add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

But it just doesn't work. Not sure what hook I'm really supposed to be using though.

Website is http://dev.podcamptoronto.com/
Using a social media account login system, 'wordpress social login'. But it uses the native login function itself, so I don't think it's interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many approaches to this. Mine is given below ..

1. First you store the time on which the user was logged in so that you can display the successfull login popup for X number of minutes ..

   ```
   function store_login_time($user_login, $user) {
       $userID = $user->ID;
       update_user_meta( $userID, '_login_time_', time() );
   }
   add_action('wp_login', 'store_login_time', 10, 2);
   ```
2. Then you use this code to display the code on the front page of the website for X number of minutes ( 1 minute in my sample ) using `wp_head` action ..

   ```
   function myscript() {

       $to_time = time();
       $from_time = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_login_time_', true ); 

       $diff = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);

       // This will run till 1 minute after logging in ..
       // For Seconds use 0.1 to 0.9
       if ( is_front_page() && $diff < "1" ){

           ?> 
           <script type="text/javascript">
             $( document ).ready(function() {
               $('<div class="item login">Success! You\'re now signed in.</div>').appendTo('.pop-notice').delay(6000).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });
             });
           </script>
           <?php

       }
   }
   add_action('wp_head', 'myscript');
   ```

You can add further options for user roles as per you needs.

Comment: Thanks! Made a modified version that just sets a user meta to true or false, rather than timed.

Answer (score 0):

`login_redirect` is a filter, so technically what you are doing is an abuse of the hook but more importantly, `login_redirect` runs before a [***redirect***](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php#L826) which results in a new page load. HTTP and PHP in that context is stateless meaning that code doesn't populate through a page load.

What you are going to have to do is pass an argument through the URL...

```
function my_login_redirect($redirect) {
  return esc_url(add_query_arg('lgn',true,$request));
}
add_filter('login_redirect','my_login_redirect',10);
```

Then use that variable to trigger your message either via PHP directly or with your JavaSAcript.